# How to parse JSON data using retrofit and rx?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2, reactivex

I'm trying to get the data from JSON using retrofit and rx. I followed [this tutorial](http://developine.com/kotlin-android-json-parsing-tutorial-retrofit/). But the JSON from that tutorial is a little different from mine. So I just changed how to parse it a bit. But if I get the JSON or not because I don't know how I know that the JSON is already called or not and in app it didn't show anything.

If anyone knows how it works and how to make the parse, Please guide me.

This is my code where I want to parse the JSON data in fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    rv__list_posts?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.requireContext())

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://www.thesportsdb.com/").build()

    val postsApi = retrofit.create(INetworkAPI::class.java)

    var response = postsApi.getAllPosts()

    response.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(IoScheduler()).subscribe {
        rv__list_posts.adapter = MainAdapter(listOf(it), this.requireContext())
    }
}
```

This is my interface:

```
interface INetworkAPI {
  @GET("api/v1/json/1/eventslast.php?id=133602")
  fun getAllPosts(): Observable<Team>
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
class MainAdapter(val postList: List<Team>, val context: Context) :
  RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
  ViewHolder {
    return 
    ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false))
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return 10
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.home_team.text = postList.get(position).homeTeam
    holder.itemView.home_score.text = postList.get(position).homeScore.toString()
    holder.itemView.away_team.text = postList.get(position).awayTeam
    holder.itemView.away_score.text = postList.get(position).awayScore.toString()
  }
  class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add `Team` class?

Comment: done. i added it

Answer (score 0):

Your API response have this structure:
[image]

You need to do more complex model. For example you can do `TeamResponse` class:

```
data class TeamResponse(var results: List<Team>)
```

And change `INetworkAPI` to:

```
interface INetworkAPI {
  @GET("api/v1/json/1/eventslast.php?id=133602")
  fun getAllPosts(): Observable<TeamResponse>
}
```

Then in your fragment:

```
response
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribeOn(IoScheduler())
   .subscribe {
      rv__list_posts.adapter = MainAdapter(it.results, this.requireContext())
   }
```

**EDIT:**
You can see all your api interaction in LogCat (you will can see requests and responses). For it add dependency:

```
 implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1"
```

And then change retrofit builder:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://www.thesportsdb.com/")
        .client(getClient())
        .build()
```

`getClient()` code:

```
private fun getClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }
    return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

And change all Int fields from `Team` model to String (all of these are String in response).

Comment: and in `(listOf(it.results)` it says required `List<Team>` so i change it without `listOf()`

Comment: I edited answer. Change `getClient` to Kotlin and remove `listOf()`

Comment: it says error like this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter postList
                      at com.mqa.android.footballmatchschedule.MainAdapter.<init>(MainAdapter.kt:19)
                      at com.mqa.android.footballmatchschedule.LastActivity$onCreateView$2.accept(LastActivity.kt:93)
                      at com.mqa.android.footballmatchschedule.LastActivity$onCreateView$2.accept(LastActivity.kt:37)`

Comment: Check response in LogCat. Get you correct response?

Comment: It seems that results is `null`

Comment: actually it get the correct response but i dont know why it still doesn't work `"results":[{"idEvent":"576561","idSoccerXML":"389946",...........`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182759/discussion-between-p-alexey-and-qubaisy-andiyantama).

Comment: what's parameter that they said null? is the json cannot be null?